# Does Atom have auto-complete or snippets package like for CoffeeScript atom-ternjs?

Tags: coffeescript, atom-editor

I use Atom a lot, and atom-ternjs is really good for javascript deployment.

But now I work with a team use CoffeeScript, I really love it.

Does Atom have good auto-complete tools for CoffeeScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install a [lint](/questions/tagged/lint) specifically for [coffeescript](/questions/tagged/coffeescript). To install it, use the following command in your Command Prompt:

```
$ apm install linter linter-ui-default linter-coffeelint
```